# Call async Method from a normal method c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to call an async method from a normal method. I have the following two issues here:

1. When I use `Task.Run` in class A to class B's method, JQuery is not
   receiving the call.
2. I cannot use `await` because it throws this error:

   > The await can only be used in an async method

I am not sure what the issue is with respect to the first problem I am having. Secondly, is there a way to use `await` when calling classB because it seems to work when I made a call from a different method that is async.

```cs
    public class A :IA
    {
        public A ()
    {
        consumer.Received += Received;
    }
        public void Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea)
        { 
           //get message here and send to classB 
            Task.Run(() => classB.PingMesssage(Message));
        }
    }


    public class B 
    {

       public async Task PingMesssage(string message)
        {
             await InvokeClientMethodToAllAsync("callJQueryMethod", "message"); //calling js here
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can call your async method from non-async context and wait for it by accessing the result of the task. So `YourAsyncMethod().Result`

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Received` async and await a call to `PingMessage`:

```
public async void Received(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea) {
    await classB.PingMessage(message);
}
```